# Generate Get Request with No User Agent

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-chrome, browser, user-agent

I have a website that has been experiencing errors because of null references due to poorly coded logic regarding the user agent. Basically, there has been a slew of incoming requests that contain no user agent which leads to null reference exceptions in the user agent tracking. (It contained a call to "Request.UserAgent.ToLower()) I am correcting this logic to avoid the error condition. Since I'm certain these requests are coming from specialized tools and not ordinary users, I'm also blocking empty user agents via URL rewrite rules.

I need to test both of these changes. However, I can't seem to find a user agent spoofer that will enable me to generate a simple get request with NO USER AGENT. All of the tools that I have tried will allow me to do a custom agent string, but they won't let that string be left empty and there are no options that I can find to tell it to send no user agent.

So my question is, what tools are available, for a Windows-based system, that I can use to emulate a browser request with NO USER AGENT so that I can verify that my changes are working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that value is coming from the request headers. If yes, just try
Fiddler. Go to composer tab (see below) - by default it adds User-Agent to the request, however when you delete it in the Composer it seems to disappear from the request. [image: Fiddler Composer]

Comment: It is part of the header and that worked perfectly. THANK YOU! (I sometimes forget how much can be done with Fiddler.)